# get the updated list using <rich:orderingList> after changing the order

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Hi i am new to rich:orderingList and i need to get the new list after arranging the contents in new order in jsf controller .

Following is my piece of XHTML code

```
<h:form id="editscreenrankForm">
   <a4j:outputPanel id="edit-screenrank-fields">
      <rich:orderingList value="#{currencyController.rankingList}" var="ranking"              
           itemValue="#{ranking}" itemLabel="#{ranking.code} - #{ranking.name}">
     </rich:orderingList>
  </a4j:outputPanel>
  <h:commandButton value="submit" type="submit" action="#currencyController.getList}"/>
</h:form>
```